# Connecting to SQL Server 2000 with an ASP page using VB?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, sql-server-2000

I am in need of a tutorial or guide that demonstrates  how to connect to SQL Server 2000 with ASP pages using Visual Basic.

Comment: I edited your question to make it slightly less like txtspk

Answer (score 3):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/169377

First thing to come up on a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp+sql+server+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).